# Hourly RSI calculation to match Daily RSI

Tags: indicator

I implemented the RSI calculation based on the ta4j implementation that you can find here: https://github.com/ta4j/ta4j/blob/master/ta4j-core/src/main/java/org/ta4j/core/indicators/RSIIndicator.java.

If I use hourly data instead of daily data, for the same period, I end up having very different indicators.

For example:

Calculating the RSI using daily close values for 1 year ( around 230 points ) 
Vs 
Calculating the same RSI on the same period but using Hourly data ( around 1500 points )

It will give me very different RSI values, especially the range between max and min RSI drops significantly when using more granularity.

I would like to know if this is expected, and if yes, what correction to the RSI indicator I should use to have both RSI indicator looking similar
independently of the granularity used.

For example, SMA indicators look similar if I use daily data or minute data.

As an example, here are the AAPL stock RSI 14 days with the daily close from Feb->Oct 2019.
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/AAPL/wPE6FWmX-RSI-chart-for-Stack-Exchange-question/

And the same AAPL with hourly close, with an RSI 14*7=98 period in the same period.

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/AAPL/Y5KrNSfP-The-RSI-based-on-hourly-ticks/

As we can see, these two RSI look very different.

What modification to the original RSI formula needs to be made for these two look similar?